# DataTable Select vs List<T> LINQ Performance

Tags: c#, .net, linq, performance, datatable

I have an app that does an SQL and loads a set of data into a datatable. As part of the processing there are  6 or 7 DataTable.Select() to filter some data. Each item that needs processing takes 300ms.  There are 5000 items to process so takes 25 mins. This is unacceptable.

Would creating POCO's and loading them into a List and then using LINQ to query the list be quicker than using DataTable.Select?

Thanks

**UPDATE:** I have delved in a bit more and there are 2 datatables each with around 15000 records.  The 2 queries used to populate the datatables take a second each. It then takes 25mins to loop over 5000 items in a Dictionary's values property and do 5 DataTable.Select's

eg/

```
foreach (OutputRecord Mailpiece in DictionaryMailpieces.Values)
{
    try
    {
        DataRow[] R = DataTable1.Select("MAILPIECE = " + Mailpiece.MailpieceSetSequenceNumber + " AND (STATUS = 4034 OR STATUS = 4037)", "DAL_DATE desc");
        if (R != null && R.Length > 0)
        {
        }
    }
    catch
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: `DataTable.Select()` and `LINQ` on a  `List` are going to do effectively the same thing.  You need to reconsider your logic, perhaps by adding some caching?  You could also provide some examples of the kinds of filtering your are doing.  For instance, if you are looking up individual rows with a `Select`, it might be more efficient to walk through the data set row by row in a single loop.

Comment: What are the Select method filter pattern? It takes too long in my opinion.

Comment: Don't guess at performance problems, whip out a profiler and measure them.

Comment: Please can you recommend an easy to understand/setup profiler?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Funny there is no "SQL" tag associated with your question. I suggest, you learn how to use the SQL language and its benefits. From what you say, it is likely you are, with your code, creating a lot of [Cartesian products](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product), instead of leveraging the [Relational Database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database) facilities (joins, indexes, etc.)

Using cross joins of DataTables or Lists or anything similar will always lead to heavy performance degradation, whatever language or platform is used.

That said, you could use LINQ because it's capable of producing smart SQL (dynamically), but you still want to avoid all ToList(), ToArray() and similar extension methods on IEnumerable(T) that summon all the underlying data (keep it enumerable from end to end and leverage "object streaming" whenever possible). If you understand really what is a Relational Database and how to use it efficiently, you will be a better LINQ developer.

Comment: There isnt a SQL problem, the query takes 1 second for 15000 rows

Comment: Simon was getting at the fact that doing this sort of data manipulation in your app is slow and memory intensive. As you stated the database is fast so why not let it do all of the work?

Answer (score 3):

Almost anything will be faster than manipulating an ADO.NET `DataTable` -- they are not designed for fast retrieval in any sense.  You should also put the objects into an appropriate data structure; a `DataTable` is a red-black binary tree of rows, so if you don't want that, you shouldn't use one.

If you're just using the `DataTable` as a sequential collection of rows with fields, then you'll probably see a factor of 2 or more speedup just by replacing the `DataTable` with a `List<T>` and replacing your `Select` calls with `Where` calls, although it depends on what you're doing with it.

EDIT:  Actually, I changed my mind.  Nothing you could be doing sorting-or-filtering-wise with 5000 items in a `DataTable` implies a cost of anywhere close to 300ms, so the bottleneck is probably unrelated.

Comment: +1 Thank you.  I've been looking for verification that DataTables are RedBlack Tree's internally.  How often are Rows in a DataTable ever searched?  Well, primary key and foriegn key constraints is probably a huge factor why DataTables use RBTrees.  But 90% of the time I see DataTables used, it's a 2D array where this is never used.  Making it a horrible data structure when you have a large amount of data.

Answer (score 0):

Using LINQ will most likely not provide a huge speed improvement, in and of itself.  That being said, you could potentially use PLINQ to simplify the parallelization of the processing, which could allow this to scale better on multicore systems.  This tends to be much simpler when using POCOs instead of DataTable, as DataTable is not thread safe, and has concurrency issues.

That being said - I suspect that profiling this process would, overall, give you a much better potential improvement, as it would allow you to find and correct any bottlenecks.  If there are no specific bottlenecks, and the process just requires that amount of raw processing, caching may also help.  In addition, it's possible that leaving the data on the database and using some form of ORM may help, as well, as the "6 or 7" filter operations could be run on a scalable server instead of locally.  All of this is highly dependent on the nature of your data and algorithm, however, so it would require some careful consideration to determine whether it would be beneficial or detrimental overall.

Answer (score -1):

> Would creating POCO's and loading them into a List and then using LINQ to query the list be quicker than using DataTable.Select?

We have no idea, you didn't give us enough information. We have no idea how your method is coded (maybe you have an errant `Thread.Sleep(300)` buried in your code; we can't tell).

More importantly, we need to know where the bottleneck is. To figure that out, you need a profiler. Get one and then once you know what the bottleneck is, we can probably help you eek out some extra performance.

That said, switching to LINQ probably isn't going to single-handedly be the solution to your performance problems. Something else is wrong, and whether it is coded using `DataTable`s and LINQ is mostly irrelevant. The performance gains are going to come from having the right plan of attack to your problem; `DataTable`s and LINQ are just ways of implementing that plan of attack.

Comment: Please can you recommend an easy to understand/setup profiler?